# Can no longer add VMs on Xen/DRBD/Pacemaker Cluster

Tags: debian, xen, pacemaker, virsh

OS: Debian 7.3 & 7.6

Problem:

Every attempt to manipulate (create, migrate or even list) the VM's with virsh causes this "Failed to get host power capabilities" warning. I manage a standalone Xen virtual host which produces the same warning & although it can be annoying, I've found that I can simply ignore it. Unfortunately, ignoring the warning on the Cluster, which incorporates the ocf.heartbeat.VirtualDomain resource handler, doesn't appear to be an option. Basically Pacemaker creates & manages the VMs using virsh. Now I discover, I can no longer add any new resources (VMs). I believe the problem to be libvirt (0.9.12.3) & this "Failed to find..." warning. Google/Debian say there is a bug in libvirt-bin & suggest using an earlier version of the software.

Questions:

1. Has anybody experienced similar restrictions (failure to add resources) in a Xen/Pacemaker cluster?
2. If so, what was the cause? & how has the problem been dealt with?
3. I believe I could avoid this issue be by replacing ocf.heartbeat.VirtualDomain with ocf.heartbeat.Xen. Has anybody made a similar experience?

I am grateful for any tips, experience or suggestions that maybe offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried changing libvirt for a older version but it didn't bring the desired effect so I have replaced the resource agent (ocf.heartbeat.VirtualDomain for ocf.heartbeat.Xen). This workaround solves my problem without dealing with the warning, which is there. But I am satisfied.